# how can I spy on a function with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I have a function that calls another function

```
const getArtist = (id) => {
// builds params for other function
return otherFuntion(params);
}
```

I want to verify that when I call `getArtist(someValue)`, otherFunction gets called with the right arguments.
How can I accomplish that with jest ?

```
describe('getArtist function', () => {
    it('should call otherFunction with the right params', () => {
        // how can I get a handle on the mock of otherFunction to see
        // if it was called correctly ?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to mock out the imported function at compile time if it's a public function. If it's a private function then you definitely don't want to mock it out.

You should probably just test the return value of `otherFuntion` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So you are really calling the function **otherFuntion(params)** so I would rather check if return of your **getArtist** functions gives the same results as **otherFunction** called with right params.

```
describe('getArtist function', () => {
  it('should call otherFunction with the right params', () => {
    expect(getArtist(id)).toBe(otherFunction(params));
  });
});
```

Or create special function for generate params and test it separatly. Like **prepareArtistParams** and use it inside:

```
const getArtist = (id) => {
  const params = prepareArtistParams(id);
  return otherFuntion(params);
}

describe('otherFuntion function', () => {
  it('should create right params', () => {
    expect(prepareArtistParams(id)).toBe(params);
  });
});
```